# Rendering two textures with blending and alpha test

Tags: opengl, textures, blending, transparency, jogl

What I am looking for is the following: I have a circle on a square image, alpha is 0 at the corners

[image]

and also a square shadow, alpha is 0 everywhere else

[image]

I would like to have as final result a blending of these two renders, plus the shadow not being rendered outside the circle

How could I achieve that?

Comment: "blending of these two renders" What does that mean? What kind of "blending" are you looking for?

Comment: Could you [provide a picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words) of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean, the shadow over the circle, like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1401029/Result.png but "masking" the shadow over the circle

Comment: @lorancou http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1401029/Result.png

Comment: @elect I don't get it, is that what you want, or what you've achieved so far?

Comment: @lorancou what I achieved do far. But I would like that the shadows dont get rendered outside the green circle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is a stencil buffer. Render your circle with stencil write, and then change opengl state so that only the bits that have the stencil bits on should be updated, and then render your shadow thingy.